# What is the difference between Scala's case class and class?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, case-class

I searched in Google to find the differences between a `case class` and a `class`. Everyone mentions that when you want to do pattern matching on the class, use case class. Otherwise use classes and also mentioning some extra perks like equals and hash code overriding. But are these the only reasons why one should use a case class instead of class?

I guess there should be some very important reason for this feature in Scala. What is the explanation or is there a resource to learn more about the Scala case classes from?

Answer (score 448, accepted):

Case classes can be seen as *plain and immutable data-holding objects that should exclusively depend on their constructor arguments*.

This functional concept allows us to

- use a compact initialization syntax (`Node(1, Leaf(2), None))`)
- decompose them using pattern matching
- have equality comparisons implicitly defined

In combination with inheritance, case classes are used to mimic [algebraic datatypes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Discriminated_Unions).

If an object performs stateful computations on the inside or exhibits other kinds of complex behaviour, it should be an ordinary class.

Comment: @Dario Thanks for the pointers. So ADT's are something like Enums?

Comment: @Teja: In some way. ADT's are kinda *parameterized enums*, extremely powerful and typesafe.

Comment: Sealed case classes are used to mimic algebraic datatypes. Otherwise the number of subclasses is not limited.

Comment: @Thomas, actually, case classes which extend sealed abstract classes are limited.

Comment: @Thomas: Correctly spoken, *case classes deriving from sealed abstract classes mimic closed algebraic datatypes* whereas the ADT is otherwise *open*.

Comment: @Dario ... and the type is otherwise open and not and a ADT. :-)

Comment: @Thomas: Yep, it's merely an existential ;)

Comment: Could they be thought of as the types one would use for Value Objects?

Comment: An important restriction seems to be that a case class cannot be extended by another case class.

Comment: *[...] plain and immutable data-holding objects [...]* Note that Scala doesn't enforce immutability of case classes: `case class Foo(var int: Int)`.

Comment: Hm... why does the link to "algeraic datatypes"  refer to F#?

Answer (score 174):

Technically, there is no difference between a class and a case class -- even if the compiler does optimize some stuff when using case classes. However, a case class is used to do away with boiler plate for a specific pattern, which is implementing [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

A very simple example of such types are trees. A binary tree, for instance, can be implemented like this:

```
sealed abstract class Tree
case class Node(left: Tree, right: Tree) extends Tree
case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree
case object EmptyLeaf extends Tree
```

That enable us to do the following:

```
// DSL-like assignment:
val treeA = Node(EmptyLeaf, Leaf(5))
val treeB = Node(Node(Leaf(2), Leaf(3)), Leaf(5))

// On Scala 2.8, modification through cloning:
val treeC = treeA.copy(left = treeB.left)

// Pretty printing:
println("Tree A: "+treeA)
println("Tree B: "+treeB)
println("Tree C: "+treeC)

// Comparison:
println("Tree A == Tree B: %s" format (treeA == treeB).toString)
println("Tree B == Tree C: %s" format (treeB == treeC).toString)

// Pattern matching:
treeA match {
  case Node(EmptyLeaf, right) => println("Can be reduced to "+right)
  case Node(left, EmptyLeaf) => println("Can be reduced to "+left)
  case _ => println(treeA+" cannot be reduced")
}

// Pattern matches can be safely done, because the compiler warns about
// non-exaustive matches:
def checkTree(t: Tree) = t match {
  case Node(EmptyLeaf, Node(left, right)) =>
  // case Node(EmptyLeaf, Leaf(el)) =>
  case Node(Node(left, right), EmptyLeaf) =>
  case Node(Leaf(el), EmptyLeaf) =>
  case Node(Node(l1, r1), Node(l2, r2)) =>
  case Node(Leaf(e1), Leaf(e2)) =>
  case Node(Node(left, right), Leaf(el)) =>
  case Node(Leaf(el), Node(left, right)) =>
  // case Node(EmptyLeaf, EmptyLeaf) =>
  case Leaf(el) =>
  case EmptyLeaf =>
}
```

Note that trees construct and deconstruct (through pattern match) with the same syntax, which is also exactly how they are printed (minus spaces).

And they can also be used with hash maps or sets, since they have a valid, stable hashCode.

Answer (score 79):

- Case classes can be pattern matched
- Case classes automatically define hashcode and equals
- Case classes automatically define getter methods for the constructor arguments.

(You already mentioned all but the last one).

Those are the only differences to regular classes.

Comment: Setters are not generated for case classes unless "var" is specified in the constructor argument, in which case you get the same getter/setter generation as regular classes.

Comment: @Mitch: True, my bad. Fixed now.

Comment: You omitted 2 differences, see my answer.

Comment: @MitchBlevins, regular classes [don't always have](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14694858/615784) getter/setter generation.

Comment: Case classes define unapply method that's why they can be pattern matched.

Comment: Hey, don't agree with statement "Those are only diffs".
CASE class automatically creates COMPANION object with implemented FACTORY apply(). Case classes are SERIALIZABLE: you can use instance in distributed platform, as yore with jvm here (Akka, f.e.). And mutch more. So, don't be so strict.

Answer (score 32):

No one mentioned that case classes have `val` constructor parameters yet this is also the default for regular classes (which [I think is an inconsistency](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-debate/VPdNmvyneyU/mzEkjSxLNMcJ) in the design of Scala). Dario implied such where he noted they are "*immutable*".

Note you can override the default by prepending the each constructor argument with `var` for case classes. However, making case classes mutable causes their `equals` and `hashCode` methods to be time variant.[1]

*sepp2k* already mentioned that case classes automatically generate `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

Also no one mentioned that case classes automatically create a companion `object` with the same name as the class, which contains `apply` and `unapply` methods. The `apply` method enables constructing instances without prepending with `new`. The `unapply` extractor method enables the pattern matching that others mentioned.

Also the compiler optimizes the speed of `match`-`case` pattern matching for case classes[2].

[1] [Case Classes Are Cool](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/case-classes-are-cool)

[2] [Case Classes and Extractors, pg 15](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~emir/written/MatchingObjectsWithPatterns-TR.pdf).

Answer (score 30):

No one mentioned that case classes are also instances of `Product` and thus inherit these methods:

```
def productElement(n: Int): Any
def productArity: Int
def productIterator: Iterator[Any]
```

where the `productArity` returns the number of class parameters, `productElement(i)` returns the *i*<sup>th</sup> parameter, and `productIterator` allows iterating through them.

Comment: They aren't instances of Product1, Product2, etc., however.

Answer (score 18):

The case class construct in Scala can also be seen as a convenience to remove some boilerplate.

When constructing a case class Scala gives you the following.

- It creates a class as well as its companion object
- Its companion object implements the `apply` method that you are able to use as a factory method. You get the syntactic sugar advantage of not having to use the new keyword.

  ---

Because the class is immutable you get accessors, which are just the variables (or properties) of the class but no mutators (so no ability to change the variables). The constructor parameters are automatically available to you as public read only fields. Much nicer to use than Java bean construct.

- You also get `hashCode`, `equals`, and `toString` methods by default and the `equals` method compares an object structurally. A `copy` method is generated to be able to clone an object (with some fields having new values provided to the method).

The biggest advantage as has been mentioned previously is the fact that you can pattern match on case classes. The reason for this is because you get the `unapply` method which lets you deconstruct a case class to extract its fields.

---

In essence what you are getting from Scala when creating a case class (or a case object if your class takes no arguments) is a  singleton object which serves the purpose as a *factory* and as an *extractor* .

Comment: Why would you need a copy of an immutable object?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Because the `copy` method can modify the fields: `val x = y.copy(foo="newValue")`

Comment: Thank you for this description. While there are higher voted answers, this one best describes the distinctions of the case in plain english. As someone who is new to scala this made the most sense to me and is fairly complete.

Answer (score 15):

Apart from what people have already said, there are some more basic differences between `class` and `case class`

1.`Case Class` doesn't need explicit `new`, while class need to be called with `new`

```
val classInst = new MyClass(...)  // For classes
val classInst = MyClass(..)       // For case class
```

2.By Default constructors parameters are private in `class` , while its public in `case class`

```
// For class
class MyClass(x:Int) { }
val classInst = new MyClass(10)

classInst.x   // FAILURE : can't access

// For caseClass
case class MyClass(x:Int) { }
val classInst = MyClass(10)

classInst.x   // SUCCESS
```

3.`case class` compare themselves by value

```
// For Class
class MyClass(x:Int) { }
 
val classInst = new MyClass(10)
val classInst2 = new MyClass(10)

classInst == classInst2 // FALSE

// For Case Class
case class MyClass(x:Int) { }
 
val classInst = MyClass(10)
val classInst2 = MyClass(10)

classInst == classInst2 // TRUE
```

Answer (score 11):

To have the ultimate understanding of what is a case class:

let's assume the following case class definition:

```
case class Foo(foo:String, bar: Int)
```

and then do the following in the terminal:

```
$ scalac -print src/main/scala/Foo.scala
```

Scala 2.12.8 will output:

```
...
case class Foo extends Object with Product with Serializable {

  <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> private[this] val foo: String = _;

  <stable> <caseaccessor> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def foo(): String = Foo.this.foo;

  <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> private[this] val bar: Int = _;

  <stable> <caseaccessor> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def bar(): Int = Foo.this.bar;

  <synthetic> def copy(foo: String, bar: Int): Foo = new Foo(foo, bar);

  <synthetic> def copy$default$1(): String = Foo.this.foo();

  <synthetic> def copy$default$2(): Int = Foo.this.bar();

  override <synthetic> def productPrefix(): String = "Foo";

  <synthetic> def productArity(): Int = 2;

  <synthetic> def productElement(x$1: Int): Object = {
    case <synthetic> val x1: Int = x$1;
        (x1: Int) match {
            case 0 => Foo.this.foo()
            case 1 => scala.Int.box(Foo.this.bar())
            case _ => throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(scala.Int.box(x$1).toString())
        }
  };

  override <synthetic> def productIterator(): Iterator = scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime.typedProductIterator(Foo.this);

  <synthetic> def canEqual(x$1: Object): Boolean = x$1.$isInstanceOf[Foo]();

  override <synthetic> def hashCode(): Int = {
     <synthetic> var acc: Int = -889275714;
     acc = scala.runtime.Statics.mix(acc, scala.runtime.Statics.anyHash(Foo.this.foo()));
     acc = scala.runtime.Statics.mix(acc, Foo.this.bar());
     scala.runtime.Statics.finalizeHash(acc, 2)
  };

  override <synthetic> def toString(): String = scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._toString(Foo.this);

  override <synthetic> def equals(x$1: Object): Boolean = Foo.this.eq(x$1).||({
      case <synthetic> val x1: Object = x$1;
        case5(){
          if (x1.$isInstanceOf[Foo]())
            matchEnd4(true)
          else
            case6()
        };
        case6(){
          matchEnd4(false)
        };
        matchEnd4(x: Boolean){
          x
        }
    }.&&({
      <synthetic> val Foo$1: Foo = x$1.$asInstanceOf[Foo]();
      Foo.this.foo().==(Foo$1.foo()).&&(Foo.this.bar().==(Foo$1.bar())).&&(Foo$1.canEqual(Foo.this))
  }));

  def <init>(foo: String, bar: Int): Foo = {
    Foo.this.foo = foo;
    Foo.this.bar = bar;
    Foo.super.<init>();
    Foo.super./*Product*/$init$();
    ()
  }
};

<synthetic> object Foo extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction2 with Serializable {

  final override <synthetic> def toString(): String = "Foo";

  case <synthetic> def apply(foo: String, bar: Int): Foo = new Foo(foo, bar);

  case <synthetic> def unapply(x$0: Foo): Option =
     if (x$0.==(null))
        scala.None
     else
        new Some(new Tuple2(x$0.foo(), scala.Int.box(x$0.bar())));

  <synthetic> private def readResolve(): Object = Foo;

  case <synthetic> <bridge> <artifact> def apply(v1: Object, v2: Object): Object = Foo.this.apply(v1.$asInstanceOf[String](), scala.Int.unbox(v2));

  def <init>(): Foo.type = {
    Foo.super.<init>();
    ()
  }
}
...
```

As we can see Scala compiler produces a regular class `Foo` and companion-object `Foo`.

Let's go through the compiled class and comment on what we have got:

- the internal state of the `Foo` class, immutable:

```
val foo: String
val bar: Int
```

- getters:

```
def foo(): String
def bar(): Int
```

- copy methods:

```
def copy(foo: String, bar: Int): Foo
def copy$default$1(): String
def copy$default$2(): Int
```

- implementing `scala.Product` trait:

```
override def productPrefix(): String
def productArity(): Int
def productElement(x$1: Int): Object
override def productIterator(): Iterator
```

- implementing `scala.Equals` trait for make case class instances comparable for equality by `==`:

```
def canEqual(x$1: Object): Boolean
override def equals(x$1: Object): Boolean
```

- overriding `java.lang.Object.hashCode` for obeying the equals-hashcode contract:

```
override <synthetic> def hashCode(): Int
```

- overriding `java.lang.Object.toString` :

```
override def toString(): String
```

- constructor for instantiation by `new` keyword:

```
def <init>(foo: String, bar: Int): Foo
```

Object Foo:
 - method `apply` for instantiation without `new` keyword:

```
case <synthetic> def apply(foo: String, bar: Int): Foo = new Foo(foo, bar);
```

- extractor method `unupply` for using case class Foo in pattern matching:

```
case <synthetic> def unapply(x$0: Foo): Option
```

- method to protect object as singleton from deserialization for not letting produce one more instance:

```
<synthetic> private def readResolve(): Object = Foo;
```

- object Foo extends `scala.runtime.AbstractFunction2` for doing such trick:

```
scala> case class Foo(foo:String, bar: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> Foo.tupled
res1: ((String, Int)) => Foo = scala.Function2$$Lambda$224/1935637221@9ab310b
```

`tupled` from object returns a funtion to create a new Foo by applying a tuple of 2 elements.

So case class is just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 7):

According to Scala's [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html):

> Case classes are just regular classes that are:
>
> - Immutable by default
> - Decomposable through [pattern matching](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html)
> - Compared by structural equality instead of by reference
> - Succinct to instantiate and operate on

Another feature of the **case** keyword is the compiler automatically generates several methods for us, including the familiar toString, equals, and hashCode methods in Java.

Answer (score 6):

Class:

```
scala> class Animal(name:String)
defined class Animal

scala> val an1 = new Animal("Padddington")
an1: Animal = Animal@748860cc

scala> an1.name
<console>:14: error: value name is not a member of Animal
       an1.name
           ^
```

But if we use same code but use case class:

```
scala> case class Animal(name:String)
defined class Animal

scala> val an2 = new Animal("Paddington")
an2: Animal = Animal(Paddington)

scala> an2.name
res12: String = Paddington


scala> an2 == Animal("fred")
res14: Boolean = false

scala> an2 == Animal("Paddington")
res15: Boolean = true
```

Person class:

```
scala> case class Person(first:String,last:String,age:Int)
defined class Person

scala> val harry = new Person("Harry","Potter",30)
harry: Person = Person(Harry,Potter,30)

scala> harry
res16: Person = Person(Harry,Potter,30)
scala> harry.first = "Saily"
<console>:14: error: reassignment to val
       harry.first = "Saily"
                   ^
scala>val saily =  harry.copy(first="Saily")
res17: Person = Person(Saily,Potter,30)

scala> harry.copy(age = harry.age+1)
res18: Person = Person(Harry,Potter,31)
```

Pattern Matching:

```
scala> harry match {
     | case Person("Harry",_,age) => println(age)
     | case _ => println("no match")
     | }
30

scala> res17 match {
     | case Person("Harry",_,age) => println(age)
     | case _ => println("no match")
     | }
no match
```

object: singleton:

```
scala> case class Person(first :String,last:String,age:Int)
defined class Person

scala> object Fred extends Person("Fred","Jones",22)
defined object Fred
```

Answer (score 4):

Nobody mentioned that case class companion object has `tupled` defention, which has a type:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
//Person.tupled is def tupled: ((String, Int)) => Person
```

The only use case I can find is when you need to construct case class from tuple, example:

```
val bobAsTuple = ("bob", 14)
val bob = (Person.apply _).tupled(bobAsTuple) //bob: Person = Person(bob,14)
```

You can do the same, without tupled, by creating object directly, but if your datasets expressed as list of tuple with arity 20(tuple with 20 elements), may be using tupled is your choise.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike classes, case classes are just used to hold data.

Case classes are flexible for data-centric applications, which means you can define data fields in case class and define business logic in a companion object. In this way, you are separating the data from the business logic.

With the copy method, you can inherit any or all required properties from the source and can change them as you like.

Answer (score 3):

A *case class* is a class that may be used with the `match/case` statement.

```
def isIdentityFun(term: Term): Boolean = term match {
  case Fun(x, Var(y)) if x == y => true
  case _ => false
}
```

You see that `case` is followed by an instance of class Fun whose 2nd parameter is a Var. This is a very nice and powerful syntax, but it cannot work with instances of any class, therefore there are some restrictions for case classes. And if these restrictions are obeyed, it is possible to automatically define hashcode and equals.

The vague phrase "a recursive decomposition mechanism via pattern matching" means just "it works with `case`". (Indeed, the instance followed by `match` is compared to (matched against) the instance that follows `case`, Scala has to decompose them both, and has to recursively decompose what they are made of.)

What *case classes* are useful for? The [Wikipedia article about Algebraic Data Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) gives two good classical examples, lists and trees. Support for algebraic data types (including knowing how to compare them) is a must for any modern functional language.

What *case classes* are *not* useful for? Some objects have state, the code like `connection.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout)` is not for case classes.

And now you can read [A Tour of Scala: Case Classes](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/107)

Answer (score 3):

I think overall all the answers have given a semantic explanation about classes and case classes.
This could be very much relevant, but every newbie in scala should know what happens when you create a case class. I have written [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50670165/2511142) answer, which explains case class in a nutshell.

Every programmer should know that if they are using any pre-built functions, then they are writing a comparatively less code, which is enabling them by giving the power to write most optimized code, but power comes with great responsibilities. So, use prebuilt functions with very cautions.

Some developers avoid writing case classes due to additional 20 methods, which you can see by disassembling class file.

Please [refer this link if you want to check all the methods inside a case class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50670165/2511142).

Answer (score 2):

One important issue not mentioned in earlier answers is that of **identity**. Objects of regular classes have identity, so even if two objects have identical values for all their fields, they are still different objects. For case class instances however, equality is defined in purely terms of the values of the object's fields.

Answer (score 1):

- Case classes define a compagnon object with apply and unapply methods
- Case classes extends Serializable
- Case classes define equals hashCode and copy methods
- All attributes of the constructor are val (syntactic sugar)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the key features of `case classes` are listed below

1. case classes are immutable.
2. You can instantiate case classes without `new` keyword.
3. case classes can be compared by value

Sample scala code on scala fiddle, taken from the scala docs.

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/34XEQyE/0