# Do scala constructor parameters default to private val?

Tags: scala, scala-primary-constructor

I have been trying:

```
class Foo(bar: Int)
```

vs:

```
class Foo(private val bar: Int)
```

and they seem to behave the same although I couldn't find anywhere saying that `(bar:
Int)` expands to `(private val bar: Int)` so my question is, are these
identical/similar?

On a side note, I have been trying to use `-Xprint:typer` on these code pieces and they
produce the same code except for an extra line in the second one. How do I
read that extra line?

```
..
class Foo extends scala.AnyRef {
  <paramaccessor> private[this] val bar: Int = _;
  def <init>(bar: Int): this.Foo = {
    Foo.super.<init>();
    ()
  }
}
..


..
class Foo extends scala.AnyRef {
  <paramaccessor> private[this] val bar: Int = _;
  <stable> <accessor> <paramaccessor> private def bar: Int = Foo.this.bar;
  def <init>(bar: Int): this.Foo = {
    Foo.super.<init>();
    ()
  }
}
..
```

Answer (score 187, accepted):

`bar: Int`

This is barely a constructor parameter. If this variable is not used anywhere except the constructor, it remains there. No field is generated. Otherwise `private val bar` field is created and value of `bar` parameter is assigned to it. No getter is created.

`private val bar: Int`

Such declaration of parameter will create `private val bar` field with private getter. This behavior is the same as above no matter if the parameter was used beside the constructor (e.g. in `toString()` or not).

`val bar: Int`

Same as above but Scala-like getter is public

`bar: Int` in case classes

When case classes are involved, by default each parameter has `val` modifier.

Comment: In case classes all parameters will become "public" `val`.

Comment: @om-nom-nom: sorry, I don't get it. Should I improve formatting/structure to make it more readable?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I'm just a little bit grumpy about letters size ;-) don't take it seriously

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: `var` is available and meaningful to render constructor parameters into (mutable) class properties both in non-`case` and `case` classes.

Comment: @RandallSchulz: you are right, +1. I focused on `val` because that's what OP asked for and `val` is more idiomatic.

Comment: In 'Scala for the Impatient' book written that `bar: Int` compiled to `private[this] val bar: Int`

Comment: Having just bumped into this, if you're going to use reflection then you probably want `private val bar: Int` otherwise just roll with `bar: Int`.

Answer (score 116):

In the first case, `bar` is only a constructor parameter. Since the main constructor is the content of the class itself, it is accessible in it, but only from this very instance. So it is almost equivalent to:

```
class Foo(private[this] val bar:Int)
```

On the other hand, in the second case `bar` is a *normal* private field, so it is accessible to this instance **and** other instances of `Foo`.
For example, this compiles fine:

```
class Foo(private val bar: Int) {
  def otherBar(f: Foo) {
    println(f.bar) // access bar of another foo
  }
}
```

And runs:

```
scala> val a = new Foo(1)
a: Foo = Foo@7a99d0af

scala> a.otherBar(new Foo(3))
3
```

But this doesn't:

```
class Foo(bar: Int) {
  def otherBar(f: Foo) {
    println(f.bar) // error! cannot access bar of another foo
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a better answer than the accepted one; it highlights the difference between bare `bar: Int` and `private val ...`.