# Defining classes: difference between var, val and leaving it out?

Tags: class, scala

What would be the difference between the following three Scala declarations? I understand the [general distinction between val and var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791408/what-is-the-difference-between-a-var-and-val-definition-in-scala).

```
class A(x: T){ ... }
class B(val x: T){ ... }
class C(var x: T){ ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference between `A` and `B` (both `val` and `var` create accessor):

```
class A(a: Int) {}

// Doesn't compile (value a is not a member of)
// (new A(1)).a

class B(val b: Int) {}

(new B(1)).b                                    //> res0: Int = 1
```

Comment: To further clarify, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694712/do-scala-constructor-parameters-default-to-private-val