# Accessibility of primary constructor parameters in scala

Tags: scala, constructor

I am having hard time to understand the concept of primary constructor and it's parameters. What I have understood till now is: if we define a class as following

```
class Example(a: Int, b: Int)
```

Scala compiler generates a primary constructor of the class Examples with the above two parameters. But, it doesn't defines fields *a* and *b* in the class *Example*'s definition. But if we define

```
class Example(val a: Int, val b: Int)
```

scala compiler generates the primary constructor as above and adds two fields in the class definition.

Now the problem comes when I am trying an example like

```
class PrimaryConstructor(a: Int, b: Int){
    override def toString() = "PrimaryConstructor(" + this.a + ", " + this.b + ")"
}
```

The above code compiles well even if there is no fields named either *a* or *b*. I am not able to understand that if there are no any fields as such then how I am able to access them using *this*: the current object reference.

```
object Main{
    def main(args: Array[String]){
            val primaryConstructor = new PrimaryConstructor(1, 2)
            println(primaryConstructor.a)
    }
}
```

While if I try to access them from out side the class definition as above, I get the following error message after compilation.

```
error: value a is not a member of PrimaryConstructor
    println(primaryConstructor.a)
```

I can understand this. But, how can I access those fields using *this*? Please help me to understand this.

Comment: If you have some Javascript experience, try abandoning the Java notion of a class and instead think of a class as closure (function) over the parameters in the primary constructor. The notion of "everything as a closure" is a core concept of scala which is very powerful once you grok it. A primary constructor ensures that there is a single canonical representation of state to which a class associates behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically generates a private val, so

```
class A(a:Int) {
    def func = a
}
```

and

```
class A(private[this] val a:Int) {
    def func = a
}
```

are equivalent. This may not be entirely true if you omit the function.

When a constructor parameter is referred outside the constructor body ( such as in example `func` above ), Scala generates a `private[this] val`, otherwise not.

You can check scala spec for more details or look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694712/do-scala-constructor-parameters-default-to-private-val)

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I tried to disassemble with 'javap -p PrimaryConstructor' to see private fields and that shows them all.

Answer (score 2):

Martin's answer is great:

It basically generates a private val, so

```
class A(a:Int) {
  def func = a
}
```

and

```
class A(private[this] val a:Int) {
  def func = a
}
```

are equivalent and you can access `a` from inside your class.

But, note that `class A(a: Int)` means that the field `a` is *instance* private. Meaning that you cannot write something like this:

```
class A(a: Int){
  def sum(other: A): Int = {
    this.a + other.a
  }
}
```

`other.a` is not allowed even though both instances are of the same type. You can only use `this.a`.