# What changes when you declare "val" in a class constructor?

Tags: scala

What changes in a class when you declare a constructor value with `val`? I noticed that it behaves differently below:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Foo(value: String) extends Bar
class Bar { this: Foo =>
  def go = println(value)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:9: error: not found: value value
         def go = println(value)
                          ^

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Foo(val value: String) extends Bar
class Bar { this: Foo =>
  def go = println(value)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Foo
defined class Bar
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694712/do-scala-constructor-parameters-default-to-private-val) could help you, basically having the `val` modifier creates a public getter.

Comment: @EndeNeu you're right, I'm VTC as duplicate