# Are implicits private?

Tags: scala

Given the following code:

```
class Foo[R](i: Int)(implicit ev: Ordering[R]) {
  final type T = ev.type
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error:(13, 16) private value ev escapes its defining scope as part of
>   type Foo.this.ev.type
>       type T = ev.type

Which makes me think implicits declared in a constructor are private.
Given that `T` is final it won't be overridable, so it shouldn't cause any problem. What am I missing here?

Comment: No, that error is related to dependent types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All parameters declared in a `class` constructor are `private` unless you tell the compiler they are not. This differs from a `case class` where all parameters in the first argument list are by default `public` unless you tell the compiler otherwise.

So, yes, unless you specifically add `val` or some other public-like modifier to the value, it is by default `private`. Hence, it is telling you that a private member is being made public via the way you are defining that `type`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's because it is an implicit. I think it's just because it is a class parameter (which is private). If you drop the implicit keyword it still gives the same error. see also [Do scala constructor parameters default to private val?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694712/do-scala-constructor-parameters-default-to-private-val)