# Accessibility of scala constructor parameters

Tags: scala, constructor

Clarity needed in determining the scope of Scala's constructor parameter

As per this link https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-control-visibility-constructor-fields-scala-val-var-private#comment-13237, whenever a constructor parameter is labelled as private, then no getter and setter methods will be created. But the code I have provided here works fine even though the parameter is labelled as private. 
I went through this StackOverflow link [Do scala constructor parameters default to private val?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694712/do-scala-constructor-parameters-default-to-private-val). This one & the above contradicts. Can someone please explain. The code segment is, in fact, available in the StackOverflow link.

```
class Foo(private val bar: Int) {
    def otherBar(f: Foo) {
        println(f.bar) // access bar of another foo
    }
}
```

The below line runs fine:

```
val a = new Foo(1)
a.otherBar(new Foo(3))
```

It prints 3.

As per the first link, the code should result in compile error because the parameter is private.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at the [scala language specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/05-classes-and-objects.html#private) the `private` modifier allows access

> from within the directly enclosing template and its companion module or companion class.

To allow access only from your inside the instance you can use the modifier `private[this]`. The code

```
class Foo(private[this] val bar: Int) {
  def otherBar(f: Foo) {
    println(f.bar) // access bar of another foo
  }
}
```

results in

```
[error] .../src/main/scala/sandbox/Main.scala:9:17: value bar is not a member of sandbox.Foo
[error]       println(f.bar) // access bar of another foo
[error]                 ^
[error] one error found
```

Comment: Why is `private [this] val bar` better than just `bar`?

Comment: If you only use `bar` it is just a constructor parameter, no member variable will be created in class `Foo`. The original poster asked why it was possible to access a `private` member variable from another instance

Comment: So why is having a member variable better than not having a member variable? Is it something to do with reflection? What other reason is there for creating a member that isn't needed?

Comment: If you don't need a member variable, don't use it. I agree with that. But as far as I understood, the original question was about the accessibility rules for a `private` member in Scala.

Comment: Thanks Harald for you answer! When we say "private val bar: Int" in the constructor parameter (without 'this'), a private field named 'bar' will be created with getter and setter methods. If this is correct,then the link I provided in my question needs to be corrected.

Comment: @user3103957 Yes, the first answer to the question you linked is not quite correct. A bare constructor parameter does not create a `private val` field, it is just a value that is valid inside the scope of the constructor like any other function parameter.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a constructor parameter that is only visible inside the class, don't make it a member, just make it a normal function parameter:

```
class Foo(bar: Int) {
  def otherBar(f: Foo) {
    println(f.bar) // Fails: value bar is not a member of Foo
  }
}
```

All the code inside the constructor can still access `bar`, but it is not a member of `Foo` and therefore is not visible outside the constructor.