# What's behind Scala case classes?

Tags: scala

I'm quite new to Scala but I have already used case classes. I understood what are main differences between a regular class and a case class as summarized [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312881/what-is-the-difference-between-scalas-case-class-and-class).

I do not even think to get rid of case classes, but I would like to know what's the code needed to transform for example, this:

```
class Tweet(val user: String, val text: String) {
  override def toString: String =
    "User: " + user + "\n" +
    "Text: " + text + "]"
}
```

into a full case "compatible" class. I mean, I would like to code the same "behavior" of a case class but without using `case` keyword. Is this possible or does the compiler do something that I cannot get through code (excluding optimizations)?

Once again to make clear what I'm asking, I will always use case keyword when I need a case class, but once in life time, I would like to know what the Scala compiler (in generic sense) does for me, expressed in code terms.

*edit:*
An additional doubt: will the compiler mark somehow differently my hand coded class from an standard case class so that I can observe a different behavior in execution?

Comment: The Scala compiler doesn't differentiate the two. Case classes are just normal classes but the compiler auto-generates a lot of things that go with them and so they behave differently.

You may consider a simpler answer to the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at chapter 5.3.2 "Case Classes" in the scala spec.

If I summarize correctly, the following is auto-generated:

- accessors are generated for the class elements
- an extractor object with apply/unapply is automatically generated
- a method copy is automatically added
- methods equals, hashCode, toString are overriden

You could compare the scala source and the generated java bytecode to be sure.

Comment: If feel like you could create a regular class that is technically like a case class, but the type system wouldn't know it's a case class, so maybe it could still lead to differences in use (maybe with pattern matching). But I don't knwo scala enough to be sure about this.

Comment: @giampaolo you changed your question to ask about the runtime, while ewrnli mentioned the type system, which is a compile time thing. The only difference I can think of is that the compiler will complain if you try to extend a case class with another case class (used to be possible, but it caused problems). How it would know that the class it's extending is a case class if you're importing it from elsewhere, I'm not sure.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge: ok, I changed last sentence. I hope is more clear now.