# Trouble with constructors in Scala

Tags: scala, constructor

It's been a while since I've used constructors at all- so naturally when I have to use one in Scala I'm having trouble.

I want to do the following: When I create a new class without passing through anything- it creates an empty vector.

Otherwise if it passes through a vector- we use that vector and define it to be used with the class.

How do I do this? I previously had

```
Class example{ 

val a: Vector[int] = Vector();
```

Then I'm lost. I was thinking of doing something like

```
Class example{ 


val a: Vector[Int] = Vector() 


def this(vector: Vector[Int]){ 
  this{ 
   a = vector
  }
 }
```

But I'm getting tons of errors. Can anyone help? I'm trying to find my scala book but I can't find it- I know it had a good section on constructors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you want a constructor with a default argument:

```
class example(val a : Vector[Int] = Vector())
```

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to do this by constructor overloading, it looks like this:

```
class Example(val a: Vector[Int]) {    
  def this() = this(Vector())
}
```

---

Personal-opinion addendum: Overloading and default arguments are often good to avoid. I'd recommend just making a different function that calls the constructor:

```
class Example(val a: Vector[Int])

object Example {
  def empty = new Example(Vector())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case class Example(a: Vector[Int] = Vector())
```

No need to put the `val` keyword.

Also, using the `case` keywork you get:

- a compact initialisation syntax: `Example(Vector(1,2))`, instead of `new Example(Vector(1,2))`
- pattern matching for you class
- equality comparisons implicitly defined and pretty toString

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2312936/1706351)