# Why doesn't Scala allow one to instantiate a class without using the "new" operator?

Tags: scala

I know we cant get that effect by defining by ourselves an `apply()` method on the companion object, but for all purposes the only thing I end up seeing in Scala code-bases is that everyone will just define apply() methods for each of their classes, thus leading to a lot of boilerplate code.

F#, for instance, will allow the instantiation of objects without new by default (other than for disposables).

Is there any reason for this decision?

Comment: You can instantiate an instance of a case class without use of new. http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html

Comment: With case classes, the companion object and the `apply` method is generated automatically for you, so you don't have to write it yourself.

Comment: You probably won't get an answer, as this might have been a decision simply for being similar to Java. Personally, I would have preferred that the `new` keyword didn't exists and you would simply write `Foo()` or `Foo.new()`. Perhaps this was dealt with in the Scala-Virtualized project. Also see: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/47678/why-did-memory-managed-languages-like-java-javascript-and-c-retain-the-new

Comment: I believe this is a hangover from java (and I can't find any evidence this was a concious decision). Like others have said, case classes do this automatically - there is a good comparison between the two here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312881/what-is-the-difference-between-scalas-case-class-and-class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been discussed a while back on the [scala-language mailing list](http://scala-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/quot-new-quot-keyword-td1989540.html).

Martin Odersky points out:

> One problem with leaving out `new` is that ambiguities arise for anonymous classes: Instead of
>
> ```
> new Foo(x) { def y = x + x }
> ```
>
> you'd get:
>
> ```
> Foo(x) { def y = x + x }
> ```
>
> The parser would reject this, because it thinks that the braces { ... } enclose a function argument,
>   so definitions would not be allowed.

I would also add that you'll have problems with parameter-less constructors. Like

```
class Foo
```

How would you instantiate this, especially if there was a companion object? Of course, one could have kept `new` for these cases as an optional keyword.

A more theoretical reflection is that in `class Foo`, `Foo` is a type not a value. In general, you cannot call any methods on a type, such as synthetic `apply()` or a hypothetical `.new()`. For case classes `apply` is defined on the companion object which *is a value*. Then adding a synthetic `apply` to any class would imply that you always get a (synthetic) companion object for any class.

It would not have been impossible to do away with the `new`. In the experimental Scala-Virtualized project you [do have a virtual `new`](https://github.com/tiarkrompf/scala-virtualized/wiki/Virtualized-Scala-Reference#virtualized-new-struct-types). For the same aesthetic question one could have done away with `if` and `while` etc.