# Scala Companion Objects and Apply method

Tags: scala

I'm trying to make this statement work in my Scala code:

```
val dvd1 = Item(new Description("The Matrix DVD", 15.50, "DVD World"))
```

I have the following classes and companion object:

```
class Item(){
    private var id = 0
    def getId(): Int = this.id
}

object Item{
    def apply(description: String, price: Double, supplier: String): Description = {
        new Description(description, price, supplier)
    }

    def nextId: Int = {
        this.id += 1
    }
}

class Description(description: String, price: Double, supplier: String){
    def getDescription(): String = description
    def getPrice(): Double = price
    def getSupplier(): String = supplier
}
```

And I get the following error with my apply function and nextId:

```
error: not enough arguments for method apply: (description: String, price: Double, supplier: String)Description in object Item.
Unspecified value parameters price, supplier.
    val dvd1 = Item(new Description("The Matrix DVD", 15.50, "DVD World"))
                   ^
indus.scala:16: error: value id is not a member of object Item
        this.id += 1
             ^
```

It's not apparent to me what I'm doing wrong.

**Question:** What do I need to change with my apply function so that `dvd1` will work as expected. Also, nextId should increment the Item's id when `Item.nextId` is called, what's wrong there?

Comment: In Scala it's usually preferable to use case class rather than getters (or setters) like this.

Comment: Noted. I will make that change, but what about apply and nextId?

Comment: It's unclear what you want this to do, do you want Item(x,y, z) to return a Description (that somehow has an id associated, how?) This feels like a very awkward API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) you are trying to access class data from companion object which you can't.**

```
scala> case class Order(id: String)
defined class Order

scala> object Order { println(id) }
<console>:11: error: not found: value id
       object Order { println(id) }
                              ^
```

The reverse works, once you import your companion object inside class.

2) you when define `apply` inside your companion, you you have two apply functions now, one with **empty args** and one with **three args** as you defined which you want to call. Your args is wrong.

Based on your comments below, you want to have `Item` has `Description` datastructure which can be done as below using immutable classes in scala called `case class`

```
import scala.util.Random

case class Description(description: String, price: Double, supplier: String)
case class Item(id: Int, description: Description)

object Item {
  def apply(description: String, price: Double, supplier: String): Item = {
    val itemId = Random.nextInt(100)
    new Item(itemId, Description(description, price, supplier))
  }
}


//client code
val dvd1 = Item("The Matrix DVD", 15.50, "DVD World")

assert(dvd1.isInstanceOf[Item])
assert(dvd1.description.description == "The Matrix DVD")
assert(dvd1.description.price == 15.50)
assert(dvd1.description.supplier == "DVD World")
```

see code here in online scala editor - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/prayagupd/P3eKKPLnQYqDU2faESWtfA/4

Also, read [case class explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2312936/432903)

Comment: Im confused about why I need to use `case class`? Is there a better way to `apply` description from my item companion object?

Comment: Whole point of functional programming is having immutable data, thats where case class comes in scala/ other functional language call it data class etc etc. When you define as case class you can't modify the state/ variables.

Comment: hmm okay makes sense. But would you implement apply in another way? a better way if possible or is this good

Comment: Better tell me what you want to achieve in detail. In your example you are returning Description from `Item` which is weird. In your case, `dvd1` is of type `Description` not `Item`.

Comment: Well this is just for learning purposes. I was supposed to implement these classes given that I need to accomplish this `Item(new Description("The Matrix DVD", 15.50, "DVD World"))`, but I noticed you changed it to just `Item(...)` as opposed to `Item(new Description(...))`

Comment: Is there a problem with doing `Item(new Description(...))`?

Comment: There's no problem doing that but your apply function is asking for three arguments. Is it that you want item to have description??

Comment: Yes I want Item to have a description

Comment: Cool, see if updated the answer, which has Item has Description datastructure. you dont need stupid getters and setters either :)