# What is the meaning of the word "case" in scala's "case class"?

Tags: scala, terminology, case-class

I understand that `case class` causes the compiler to augment a `class` with boilerplate to implement a certain useful pattern ("[plain and immutable data-holding objects that should exclusively depend on their constructor arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2312936/684776)").

But the word "case" itself has no meaning to me in this context. I'm accustomed to its use as part of `switch` statements in C#, but that seems to have no relevance to Scala's use of the word.

I find it easier to program when I can attach words to particular meanings. Right now my mental model is `case => boilerplate`, in the same way that it could be `blurg => boilerplate`. It's a working mental model, but ambiguity makes it easy to misunderstand or to forget altogether.

So what does the word `case` have to do with what the compiler actually does?

I'm not looking for "what was in the mind of the designers" but rather "what's a rational way to relate this term to its meaning, given general knowledge of the language's design."

Comment: Because it's major use case it to be out-of-the-box pattern-matched with `value match { case MyCaseClass(arg1, arg2) => ... }`.

Comment: The only peope who can objectively answer this would be the creators of the Language _(principally Prof. Martin Ordesky)_. But I believe the idea is that since case classes are meant to be **Pattern matched**, it makes sense to use `case` there.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez fair. I rephrased the last line to be less opinion-y. I'm not looking for "what was in the mind of the designers" but rather "what's a rational way to relate this term to its meaning, given general knowledge of the language's design."

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw I guess you can either, use the word to be associated with **Pattern Matching** _(which is one of the main use cases of case classes)_, or you can just leave it as the word used to represent an immutable type-heterogeneous tuple of values _(formally know as a sum type, with is half the definition of an ADT)_. - If you think about it, there isn't really a reason for a class being named a class, is juts the name it was chosen _(This is partially false, as the word class was borrowed from mathematics, but nowadays OOP classes are really distant of the mathematical definition)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I think both the "pattern matching" and "mathematics" relationships help resolve the "blurg" problem - thinking of the terms as mere utterances. But I agree, `class` has taken on its own meaning. Maybe `case class` will eventually reach a usage level where the same happens. I'd be happy to accept an answer which explains the relationship to pattern matching!

Comment: It's actually from the German word Käse.

Comment: @som-snytt if it’s not from the German region of Käse, is it just a sparkling tuple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the term `case` comes from [case analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_exhaustion) which is a reasoning technique enabled by special structures called [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type). By itself  `case` in `case class` might not make much sense, but when it forms a part of a `sealed` structure, which is how Scala defines ADTs, for example

```
sealed trait Number
case object Zero extends Number
case class Succ(v: Number) extends Number
```

then we see there are two *forms* of constructing `Number`s, namely using `Zero` and `Succ` *constructors*. Hence whenever we have to think about `Number`s, we at least know there are two different `case`s to consider. For example, say we want to define addition on `Number`s, then its definition will have to handle two cases, perhaps, like so

```
def sum(a: Number, b: Number): Number =
  a match {
    case Zero => b
    case Succ(v) => Succ(sum(v, b))
  }
```

where

```
sum(Succ(Zero), Succ(Zero)) == Succ(Succ(Zero)) // 1 + 1 = 2
sum(Succ(Succ(Zero)), Succ(Zero)) == Succ(Succ(Succ(Zero))) // 2 + 1 = 3
sum(Succ(Zero), Succ(Succ(Zero))) == Succ(Succ(Succ(Zero))) // 1 + 2 = 3
sum(Zero, Succ(Succ(Zero))) == Succ(Succ(Zero)) // 0 + 2 = 2
sum(Succ(Succ(Zero)), Zero) == Succ(Succ(Zero)) // 2 + 0 = 2
```

Note how Scala in order to define ADT uses terms like `class`, `object`, `trait` etc., which appear to be from the object-oriented paradigm, however ADTs conceptually have little in common with class hierarchies found in OO. Personally I find this confusing, but we must remember Scala is both functional and OO language, which might be a reason for such terminological spillover. In some other more "pure" languages `case class` of ADT is represented simply by a vertical bar `|`, say like so

```
Inductive nat : Type :=
   | O : nat
   | S : nat -> nat.
```

My suggestion would be to try not to be a "slave to words" but instead words should serve you. What is important is the **meaning** behind the words or terms, not the words themselves. Do not build mental models around the terms, instead build mental models around the heavy concepts they are struggling to carry across feeble bridges of communication. In my opinion, the concept `case` is trying to communicate is that of ADT.

Comment: I especially appreciate the analysis at the end. The heavy concepts are new to me, so I'm giving the feeble communicative bridge (the word `case`) quite the stress test. But I'll dig into case analysis and ADTs to try to work backwards to the word. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

C# has a `switch` / `case` language feature which allows controlling program flow by matching an input to a set of possible values.

```
public static GetEmail(string name)
{
  switch (name)
  {
    case "bill":
      return "bill@example.com";
    case "jane":
      return "jane@example.com";
    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

Here, `case` roughly means "in the case that the given value is equal to this one, do X."

Scala's `match` / `case` feature is sort of like C#'s feature.

```
def getEmail(name: String): Option[String] = {
  name match {
    case "bill" => Option("bill@example.com")
    case "jane" => Option("jane@example.com")
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

But it's much more powerful. It is designed to evaluate "matches" against things farm more complex than strings. To take advantage of this powerful matching feature, you define immutable data-holding classes with `case class`.

Here is a trivial, but hopefully helpful, example of a case class and its use with `match` / `case`:

```
case class Person(name: String, hasEmail: Boolean)

object EmailHelper {
  def getEmail(person: Person): Option[String] = {
    person match {
      case Person(_, false) => None
      case Person("bill", true) => Option("bill@example.com")
      case Person("jane", true) => Option("jane@example.com")
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

In short, `case class` enforces a set of constraints which make a class usable with `match` / `case`.