# Why are not class parameters not being called on the Object in Scala?

Tags: scala

In Scala how are not class parameters not truly the values being called on the object? The class parameters are part of primary constructor, so should it not be setting up the member variables of the objects, like Java? Why must we make separate fields that are the values being set on the objects? Rather than just accepting the fact, is there any good explanation?

Comment: Could you please provide a small code example to show what you mean? If I understand your question, you want to turn parameters to primary constructors into fields, which you can do by putting a `var` or `val` before the parameters.

Comment: class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) {  def add(that: Rational): Rational = new Rational( n * that.n + that.d * d, d * that.d) }                                     I understand this is improper and will cause a compile time error, but conceptually I do not get quite. Are not class parameters members of the class, can we not cal it on the object or argument that takes the object? Sorry, for formatting, I was typing on phone.

Comment: In Java, constructor parameters are also not members, so it's actually exactly the same between the two languages.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to call the parameters assigned in class's primary constructor, you will have to declare them as field.

```
class Man(name: String, age: Int) {
      def show = "My name is " + name + ", age " + age
}
```

Here `name` and `age` is **constructor parameter**. They are only accessible in the class scope.

```
class Man(val name: String, age: Int) {
      def show = "My name is " + name + ", age " + age
}
```

Notice `name` is now a variable. So now you can access `name` with `Man` class's instance.

```
val x  = new Man("Jack",10)
x.name // Jack
```

But you can not access `age` because it is a parameter not field.

Comment: Or even better use **case classes**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez case class has use case. Case class is used for data modeling class.

Answer (score 3):

> The class parameters are part of primary constructor, so should it not be setting up the member variables of the objects, like Java?

Even in Java constructor parameters do not automatically become class members

```
public class User {
    public User(String name, Integer age) {
        // do something
    }
}

User user = new User("Picard", 75);
String name = user.name // error
```

so we have to do something like

```
public class User {
    String name;
    Integer age;
    public User(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

> Why must we make separate fields that are the values being set on the objects?

Using `case class` we get that for free (along with [few other things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2312881/5205022))

```
case class User(name: String, age: Int)
val user = User("Picard", 75)
val name = user.name // ok
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Scala how are not class parameters not truly the values being called on the object?

Indeed, in certain cases class parameters are implemented as fields with the scope set to `private[this]`.

Here is an excerpt from the discussion in [scala-lang website](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/8384.html).

1. A parameter such as class Foo(x : Int) is turned into a field if it
   is referenced in one or more methods
2. Such a field is as if it had been declared as private[this] val x: Int.
3. If the parameter isn't referenced in any method, it does not give
   rise to a field.